# How to get route parameter on difference function on laravel?

Tags: laravel, routes, parameter-passing

I have a problem in my project laravel, I want to get route parameter `'id_project'` on route `'project'` to use in route `'modulproject'`. This route in one view.

This is my Route:

```
Route::get('project/{id_project}','ProjectDetailController@project');

Route::get('modulproject','ProjectDetailController@modulproject');
```

This is my Controller:

```
public function project($id_project)
{
    $project=Project::where('id','=',$id_project);
    return($project);
}

public function modulproject($id_project)
{
    $modulproject=Modul::where('id_project','=',$id_project);
    return($modulproject);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can used `Session` to get that `id_project`.

```
use Session;

public function project($id_project)
{
    Session::put('id_project',$id_project);

    $project=Project::where('id','=',$id_project);
    return($project);
}

public function modulproject()
{
   if(Session::has('id_project')){
      $modulproject=Modul::where('id_project','=',Session::get('id_project'));
      Session::forget('id_project');
      return($modulproject);
   }
   else{
       return 'redirect to other page.. (custom)';
   }

}
```